# detect if a value is numeric in all columns of a dataframe pandas and erase it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
   col  col2
0   1     1
1   B     1
2   3     D
3   4     1
4   A     2
5   2     C
6   3     2
```

I would to erase all caracters and keep only value on all columns, assigning -1 if it is a character. Something like this

```
   col  col2
0    1     1
1   -1     1
2    3    -1
3    4     1
4   -1     2
5    2    -1
6    3     2
```

How can I do that using python, thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(-1, downcast='infer') # comment by Pir

Out[480]: 
   col  col2
0    1     1
1   -1     1
2    3    -1
3    4     1
4   -1     2
5    2    -1
6    3     2
```

Or something like

```
df.mask(df.applymap(ord)>64,-1)
Out[479]: 
  col col2
0   1    1
1  -1    1
2   3   -1
3   4    1
4  -1    2
5   2   -1
6   3    2
```

Comment: What I don't like about the `applymap(ord)` solution is that the remaining numbers are left as strings.  For the `fillna`/`to_numeric` solution, you can use the argument `downcast='infer'` in the call to `fillna` to keep everything as integers: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(-1, downcast='infer')`

Answer (score 3):

We can `stack()` the df , then use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors = 'coerce'` to set invalid numerics to `NaN` , then `fillna` with -1 , and unstack() back to original shape and finally use `astype(int)` to convert to int if necessary:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.stack(),errors='coerce').fillna(-1).unstack().astype(int)
```

---

```
   col  col2
0    1     1
1   -1     1
2    3    -1
3    4     1
4   -1     2
5    2    -1
6    3     2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `df.replace` function to replace the values in the dataframe that corresponds to a character to `-1`.

**Try this:**

```
df = df.replace(r"[A-Za-z]", -1, regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
 col1 col2
0   1   1
1  -1   1
2   3  -1
3   4   1
4  -1   2
5   2  -1
6   3   2
```